# how to control Xml from XML Schema?

Tags: c#, xml

i've a XSD file and i want to check my XML from this. how can i do it? Thank in advance !

```
 XmlTextWriter objX = new XmlTextWriter(context.Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);

    objX.WriteStartDocument();

    objX.WriteStartElement("MerchantItems");
    objX.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
```

Comment: Do not use `new XmlTextWriter()`. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307379) was helpful.

Here is some consoildated code from that link which loads your XML document and validates it against the associated schema (you just need to make sure that your XML document is correctly referencing the schema):

```
using System.Xml;        // for XmlTextReader and XmlValidatingReader
using System.Xml.Schema; // for XmlSchemaCollection (which is used later)

internal class Program
{
    private static
        bool isValid = true; // If a validation error occurs,
                             // set this flag to false in the
                             // validation event handler. 

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
        xrs.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        xrs.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
        xrs.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        xrs.ValidationEventHandler += MyValidationEventHandler;

        XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("<path to xml>", xrs);

        while (r.Read())
        {
            // Can add code here to process the content.
        }

        r.Close();

        // Check whether the document is valid or invalid.
        Console.WriteLine(isValid ? "Document is valid" : "Document is invalid");

        Console.In.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void MyValidationEventHandler(object sender,
                                                ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Validation {1}: {0}", args.Message, args.Severity);
        isValid = false;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: -1: Do not use `new XmlTextReader()`. Use `XmlReader.Create()`

Comment: @Joh Fixed to use XmlTextReader.Create()!

Comment: you're still using `XmlValidatingReader`, and you should use `XmlReader.Create`, not `XmlTextReader.Create`.

Comment: @John Thanks for the input. I've learned a few things today. I've updated my example to use XmlReader.Create() instead of XmlTextReader.Create() and XmlReaderSettings instead of XmlValidatingReader.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

This is not a working example, just something to get you started

```
        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        using(XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, null))
        {
            // ... WRITE DOCUMENT HERE ...
            XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
            x.Load(ms);
            x.Validate(eventHandlerForSchema);
        }
```

Comment: -1: `new XmlTextWriter()` should not be used. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: You're right, I changed my answer to use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to write the whole xml file first. Then once you're done you can use the XmlSchema class to validate your created xml document. I don't know how to do it while you're in the process of writing the file.

Comment: Possibly John, but i think the main problem here is that hes writing the output of the XML document directly to the output stream and never has a chance to validate the document before it gets output.

Comment: you're right. The validation options are on `XmlReaderSettings`, not `XmlWriterSettings`. Comment deleted.